# Azure Web App Site Extension not extracting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Using a template and AZ CLI I install a SiteExtension for a WebApp on Windows.
The SiteExtension is consumed from a feed and I can verify the nupkg in KUDU. From the menu Site Extensions I can also see the site extension.

The issue is the extraction, it's not happening. I also tried to drop/replace the nupkg, nothing happens....

Looking for some input to solve this issue...

Comment: Why do you think it is not effective? Pls open scm site, in the same directory as wwwroot, if you find siteExtension folder, it means you have installed extension successfully.

Comment: Would you mind accept my answer for others to refer if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not necessary to extract the extension files.

You could install the extension by name or path through az command.

```
az extension add --name <extension-name>
az extension add --source <URL-or-path>
```

Once an extension is installed, it's found under the value of the `$AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR` shell variable. If this variable is unset, by default the value is `$HOME/.azure/cliextensions` on Linux and macOS, and `%USERPROFILE%\.azure\cliextensions` on Windows.

You could also install the custom extension manually. From the Debug Console, run "`mkdir SiteExtensions\FileCounterMVC`". Then navigate to the FileCounterMVC directory. If you’re using Chrome or Firefox then you can drag-drop the content of your “artifacts” folder (shown below). If you’re using IE, then you need to zip up the contents of the artifacts folder first, and then drag-drop the zip file on the right of the screen to have Debug Console unzip it.
[image]

Reference:

1. [Writing a Site Extension for Azure Websites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/writing-a-site-extension-for-azure-websites/)
2. [Use extensions with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview)